# Actions with the same parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have been making a website and have been at this multiple times before in my web development experience but I always have difficulty with it and it just seems wrong.

So I have a SectionController, in there I have

```
ActionResult Index(string sectionName)
```

and

```
ActionResult NewPost(string sectionName)
```

However the problem is that any time I link to anything I have to pass the section through as well which as you can guess is a bit annoying. What my main question is, is there anyway to make it so it isn't needed like this?

To add in something like

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
```

Into each link for pages in the a section would be rather annoying. I could make some extension probably to do something like

```
@Html.SectionLink("NewPost", "Section")
```

So it would automatically get the controller and ensure it exists in the database before moving on, but just want to figure out what other people do for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described I would use [SessionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) to save the current section.

```
Session["SectionName"] = sectionName;
```

You might also look at ViewBag or TempData if a Session is not what you are looking for.